# IntelliJ set of shortcuts not working

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ, one can opens the corresponding tool window using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>/<kbd>1</kbd>/... keyboard shortcut. However this shortcut does not work.
I'm using Debian and I verified that there is no conflict between IntelliJ and the OS keymaps. My keyboard type is AZERTY. I tried both the digits on the numpad and the main keybad. For those of the latter, I tried using them with and without the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. I also changed the keyboard layout to use the `EN` one but with no result.

Comment: What type of keyboard do you have ? Qwerty / Azery ... ?

Comment: I have the same issue on a Azerty Keyboard. (where you have to use shift to access the digits)

Comment: Issue has be raised on idea bugtracky, for some years.... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75636

Answer (score 9):

My IntelliJ shortcuts stopped working out of the blue; restart did not fix the problem.

Went to Preferences > Keymap, changed the configuration to something else, tested with the Undo shortcut, and went back and changed back to the original config, and it started working again.

Comment: The main problem to remap is to find the original map in error: the "find shortcut" by key functionnality (on the right of the screen) require you to hit the key : obviously it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the find in path (ctrl + shift + f) and replace in path (ctrl + shift + r) stopped working suddenly. Restarting the IDE did not work. I did File > Invalidate caches and restart, to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the selected keymap in the IDE. what I mean is that you should click on file, then go to settings then search for keymaps then choose a keymap of choice. I prefer netbeans then apply and restart your IDE. With that your control keys should work

Answer (score 1):

Tried on Ubuntu 20.04. Same situation here (AZERTY keyboard -aka french layout).

Here's a workaround :

- in Ubuntu Settings : go to *Region and Language* (*Pays et Langages* in French)
- In *Input Sources* (*Source de saisie*) add a new layout `English (US)` (`Anglais (US)` in French").
- re-order the input list to mke sure the `English (US)` layout is in first position.

You should have something like this :

[image: french input source but US as primary]

- make sure your keyboard layout stays French. In your status bar, you should have `English` as primary but `French` selected

[image: english as primary but french selected]

- restart IntelliJ IDEA. `Alt+0`/`1`/`...` shortcuts are now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me intellij was using a different keyboard layout.

Force studio to use french kb layout:

setxkbmap fr

https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem, on a windows machine. The cause was that I was in a different language input mode. Switching back to ENG fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround only:

- find the keymap
- remap in preferences

---

1. find the keymap:
   If you don't know the action label, you'll have to find it:

- switch temporarily to another keymap that works for your keyboard: eclipse/netbeans
- do the action that displays the shortcut: it will change to a shortcut you can enter
- Go in File/Settings - Keymap: here you have 2 search icons: on the far right you can search by key stroke.
- When she shortcut is found: remember the action name for the next:
- reswitch to your keymap copy (or create one if not already created)

2. modify the keymap

- Stay in File/Settings-Keymap menu then this time search by name
- Remove the old mapping and add yours

Here is an example:
ctrl+1 is the "quick fix" action from eclipse, it's name is "show context action" in intellij

1. display the link:
   [image]
2. search it:
   [image]
3. Export: you want to save all that work
   Export your settings by:

- `File/Manage IDE Settings/Export Settings`
- use select none then reselect "keymap (schemes)": here you are!

After unziping, it should contains an xml with that content:

```
<keymap version="1" name="Eclipse copy" parent="Eclipse">
  <action id="ActivateCommitToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt #10000e0" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateDebugToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt left_parenthesis" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateFavoritesToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt #10000e9" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateFindToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt quotedbl" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateProblemsViewToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt minus" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateProjectToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt ampersand" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateRunToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt quote" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateServicesToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt underscore" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateStructureToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt #10000e8" />
  </action>
  <action id="ActivateVersionControlToolWindow">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt #10000c7" />
  </action>
  <action id="CloseActiveTab" />
  <action id="CloseContent">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl f4" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl w" />
  </action>
  <action id="ShowIntentionActions">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="alt enter" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift ctrl ampersand" />
  </action>
  <action id="ViewImportPopups">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift ctrl m" />
  </action>
</keymap>
```

In this example I have remapped the alt 0...alt 9 which were problematic to you,, the shift-ctrl-1 for the quick fix, and ctrl-w to work as in eclipse.

4. For information: get the original mapping
   Just for information, you can get the original mappings from the installed idea resources:

   /usr/share/idea/lib/resources.jar

contains the files

- /keymaps/$default.xml
- /keymaps/Eclipse.xml
- /keymaps/Netbeans 6.5.xml etc.

It could help to list all the problematic mappings.
Eclipse parent is $default and your problematic mappings alt 0 ... alt 9 are in $default.xml
There are 20 other mappings to remap from $default: search " 0" => GotoBookmark0:control 0 ToggleBookmark0: control shift 0 ... until 9

*Side notes:

-> switching keyboards didn't work in my case (azerty/linux)

-> the double-switch of keymap was the missing information from the other answer

-> I have the last version of intellij of my linux repository and the fix doesn't seem to be included.*

Answer (score 0):

Exiting both `Razor Cortex` and `Razor Synapse`, and then restarting them, fixed it on a new Windows 11 Intellij Ultimate install (none of the previous answers worked before that unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's because another app(Sougou input) is providing the same shortcut key(Ctrl+Shift+F).

So, I change the shortcut key in other apps. After that, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Alt+0, Alt+1... worked correctly but Alt+F7 didn't. I had to change Windows display language from English to Polish (my native language).

-- EDIT
Well, seems that the next day it stopped working again...